# Call third party API based off a POST call in NODEJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I am new to JS and NodeJs and I am trying to make a web service that make a call to Open weather API to get current weather. However I have to make the POST call twice in order to see the results. I think I somewhat understand why this is, but not how to fix it.

POST call

```
    router.get("/", (request, response) => { 
    response.json({
       CurrentTemp: currentTemp,
       maxTemp: maxTemp,
       lowTemp: lowTemp,
       city: city,
       weather: weather
    })
})
```

API call  Function

```
function forecast () { 

    var url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?`
            +`q=${userCity}&appid=${API_KEY}`

        requestWeather({ url: url, json: true }, function (error, response) { 

        if (error) { 
            console.log('Unable to connect to Forecast API'); 
        } 
          else { 

            currentTemp = response.body.main.temp
            maxTemp = response.body.main.temp_max 
            lowTemp = response.body.main.temp_min
            city = response.body.name
            weather = response.body.weather

        } 
    }) 
    
}
```

Comment: `forecast` is asynchronous. It should get a callback that gets triggered when `forecast` is completed, or switch everything to promises. You shouldn't set global variables because they are shared by every user, and you're overwriting different users' results

Comment: Got it I will change the global variables now. Is changing a function a promise just changing the keyword?

Comment: You can probably change requestWeather to be promised based using `util.promisify`

Comment: I got it changed to a Promise, however now I get "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'temp')" If I try to pass in a value to set the city for the API